# how to enable proprietary software source in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

how to **enable** proprietary software source in Ubuntu 13.04 after Installation Of Ubuntu 13.04..  please tell Me

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings, click on Software & Updates, and once the window opens make sure that it matches the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you open System Settings by clicking on the gear menu at the top right of your screen

[image]

Next click on the Software and Updates icon

[image]

When the window appears, click on the Additional Drivers tab.

[image]

Select the driver you want to use and apply the changes.